# API documentation for Electrum plugin developers?

Tags: electrum

I'm browsing through some of Electrum's default plugins in the /plugins directory. It looks like plugins hook into Electrum using @hook annotation, as in this method from audio_mode:

```
@hook
def transaction_dialog(self, dialog):
    b = QPushButton()
    b.setIcon(QIcon(":icons/speaker.png"))
```

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/plugins/audio_modem/qt.py

Where can I find Electrum 3 API documentation for writing plugins such as a list of all hook function names and the arguments they take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not official by any means, but here's something I cooked up:

https://bitzuma.com/posts/an-introduction-to-plugin-development-for-the-electrum-bitcoin-wallet/

I found these hooks by iterating over Electrum's `hook_names` object.